# Question about Culture:RFC5646 and ContentDefinitions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

{Culture:RFC5646} is returning two different values for English. Currently, when a user uses ProfileEdit or SignUpSignIn they are returning different values.

For example:

ProfileEdit returns: en-us
SignUpSignIn returns: en

I am using this in the LoadUri of ContentDefinitions so that we can have the user redirected to a customized and translated html page. However, with the two return values I am having to maintain two directories "/en" and "/en-us" instead of one.

I have verified that all the parent and child policies ContentDefinition's LoadURIs are using {Culture:RFC5646}.

We have tested multiple users from different locations.

I have researched the Azure B2C IEF localization documents,  and it makes a reference to how the language is determined but it does not shed light on why the same user, with the same browser will return different values for {Culture:RFC5646}

Here is the Content Definition Load Uri for SignUpSignIn

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
<LoadUri>https://*****/b2c/IEF/{Culture:RFC5646}/selfasserted.html</LoadUri>        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
        </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

And here is the code for Profile Edit

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
<LoadUri>https://*****/b2c/IEF/{Culture:RFC5646}/updateprofile.html</LoadUri>
<RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

What I would like is that the {Culture:RFC5646} return the same value for the same user. For example, SignUpSignIn returns "en-us" and ProfileEdit returns "en-us" that way I can maintain one directory instead of two.

Comment: Hi @Christopher. Are you passing the `ui_locales` request parameter to the authorization endpoint with different language values? What if you replace `{Culture:RFC5646}` with `{Culture:LanguageName}` (which is set to the two-letter ISO code for the UI language)?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Thank you for your reply. I am not passing ui_locales. I have thought about using Culture:LanguageName however the need is to use the full langauge "en-us"

Comment: So, a new finding. I noticed that the SignUp path inherited a different Base Profile than ProfileEdit. Even though the Content Definitions were the same, as soon as I point it to the new BaseProfile it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem was being caused by the different policies were inheriting different Base Policies. Once I had them inheriting the same Base Policy, it is working as intended.