# Azure B2C Dual Language Custom User Flow Template

Tags: templates, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c, powerapps-portal

I've created a custom template for B2C Sign In User flow. I wanted to add instruction text on the top of the page in 2 languages, so I created 2 templates, uploaded them to folders in blob storage.

When I insert a link to the User flow it is working for separated languages, but once I add a wildcard value {Culture:RFC5646} (which is recommended on MS docs) it doesn't work.

Have you got any ideas or advices of how this needs to be done?

Just to add another issue to this: the language is custom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer.

Instead of {Culture:RFC5646} I've added {Culture:LanguageName} and it fixed the issue!

Link below:

[Question about Culture:RFC5646 and ContentDefinitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538263/question-about-culturerfc5646-and-contentdefinitions)

Answer (score 0):

The language customization feature allows Azure AD B2C to pass the OpenID Connect parameter ui_locales to your endpoint. Your content server can use this parameter to provide language-specific HTML pages. The important thing is that the parameters must be passed in here.

[image]

Reference : [azure b2c - custom UI - localize custom label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557284/azure-b2c-custom-ui-localize-custom-label)

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT! Thank you for your reply! That's what I do, and it's working when I run user flow, but when I'm trying to log-in through Portal it shows: sign in failed. Any ideas? Is there something wrong with Portal setup?

Comment: @RenataU Can you please paste the screen shot or GIF how you are trying?